# Search file in tree directory

Tags: linux, shell, directory

Hi I have this assignment where I have to search a file in directory tree, starting from declared directory. And I have this code, but I'm not sure if it's essentially right, cause I've never used bash shell :)

```
fileName = "sample.txt"
directory = "test/directory";

for var i in $directory/sub1 $directory/sub2 $directory/sub3
if[$fileName]
do
echo: "$filename found"
done
```

code update :

```
   listArr=( $(find "$1" -perm /a+x -type f | sed 's/\.\///g') )

    for file in "${listArr[@]}"; do
       pathArr=( $(echo "$file" | sed 's/\//\/ /g') )
       i=0
       for row in "${pathArr[@]}"; do
           printf %$(eval echo $i)s | sed 's/ /    /g'
           echo "$row"
           i=$((i + 1))
       done

done
```

Comment: This contains errors on almost every single line.  __Please__ refer to a manual.  Although, I'm certain that you'd get homework done within minutes.

Comment: I've updated my code can you tell me if it's okay now @devnull

Comment: Find a file by its name in an specified tree, is approx 22-40 characters long command, depending on the filename lenght. You really should learn some basics about the commands in your examples.

Comment: well i cant find any tutorials or guides that will help me accomplish my assignment. if i can find some small parts that will help me build the big thing i'll be quite happy but right now i'm quite pissed.